# Firebase Storage View by certain users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, firebase-console

I am new to firebase and I have developed an app which can save documents. I want to assign a role to my team member who can view "Real-Time Data" but not the "Storage" as few files are confidential. The team mate should not have access to view storage files in firebase.

Can I do this by adding rules in firebase? If yes, how?

If I cannot do this, what is the alternate?

Comment: Are you asking how to set up rules for Cloud Storage? If so, that's covered in the Getting Started Guide [Storage Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the Firebase console you can assign these broad roles to the collaborators on a project:

[image]

As you can see, Database and Storage are in the same role here, so you can't assign different permissions for them.

Luckily you can also define a [custom role](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-custom) in the Cloud console, which allows you **fine grained control over what a collaborator can do**.

You'll want to read the documentation on [granting, changing and revoking access](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access) in the Cloud documentation, and then build a role that has the necessary [Firebase product-level predefined roles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-predefined-product). Since you want the collaborator to only have [access to Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-predefined-product#realtime-database), you'll need one of these:

> Role: Firebase Realtime Database Admin
>   `roles/firebasedatabase.admin`
>
> Description: Full read/write access to
>   Realtime Database resources
>
> Realtime Database Admin permissions:
>
> - `firebasedatabase.instances.create`
> - `firebasedatabase.instances.get`
> - `firebasedatabase.instances.list`
> - `firebasedatabase.instances.update`
>
> Role: Firebase Realtime Database Viewer
>   `roles/firebasedatabase.viewer`
>
> Description:  Read-only access to Realtime Database resources
>
> Realtime Database Viewer permissions:
>
> - `firebasedatabase.instances.get`
> - `firebasedatabase.instances.list`