# How do I block changes to the Firebase Realtime database from the console

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, permissions, firebase-console

I have read a lot about read/write rules in the Realtime database, but I have not found any information on how to block changes from the console itself.

I am setting up a process where we have a repo for the content, and then push to the realtime database to deploy.

I would like to enforce this method and make it impossible to update it from the firebase console. Can this be achieved?

I still want people to have 'Editor' privilege of the rest of firebase though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in roles provide a collaborator similar permissions to groups of Firebase services, so they may not be flexible enough to allow this use-case.

Luckily you can also define a [custom role](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-custom) in the Cloud console, which allows you fine grained control over what a collaborator can do.

Also see my longer answer (with screenshots) here: [Firebase Storage View by certain users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61986342/firebase-storage-view-by-certain-users/61987449#61987449)